# Firebase IOS - Create user with phone number

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase in a current project and I understand that there is a method in Firebase called createUser(email, password). However, I was wondering if there was a way to sign up users and create users using only their phone number with firebase? I know that firebase supports phone number sign in, but does it support phone number sign up?

Comment: go through this -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the authentication providers supported by [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) can be used for initial sign up, and also signing in after that.  This includes phone numbers.

Comment: You have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Once you sign in with authentication providers supported by Firebase, authenticated user is automatically signed up. That is, sign in function act as Sign up function when used first.